# react-native-image-crop-picker crashes the app after clicking the image

Tags: android, react-native

I am uploading the image from mobile to server using react native app.
I've added `react-native-image-crop-picker` library and earlier it worked well and good.
Now it started misbehaving.
Image picker opens the camera but after clicking an image, and clicking on right tick option, app gets crashed and restarted from splash screen.

```
 ImagePicker.openCamera({
                    width: 150, height: 150, 
                    cropping: true,
                    compressImageMaxHeight: 150, compressImageMaxWidth: 150,
                    includeBase64: true, mediaType: 'photo', enableRotationGesture: true
                }).then(data => {
                    let fileData = data['data'];
                    if (fileData.length > 0) {
                        this.uploadPhotoOnServer(fileData);
                    }
              });
```

My environment setup

```
OS : Mac
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.59.5",
"react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.34.1",
```

If any solution available please let me know.

Comment: I've able to upload the image but tested that the cropper is raising an issue. any help is appreciable